# Pycharm: External Tool run in new console tab

Tags: pycharm

I've ticked "open console for tool output" for my external tools. It works but it closes all other previously opened run tabs. I want to preserve those even when running an external tool. Thus the external tool should just open a new tab not a new console. Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found it, this option is available in Advanced Settings:
[image]